# Espresso: calling openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu() opens the first item in the menu

Tags: android, functional-testing, android-espresso

I have the below espresso test:

```
    openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());

    // if I Thread.sleep() here, I can see that the MenuItem has been clicked already

    onView(withText("Sign in")) //<= click on the MenuItem
            .perform(click());

    onView(withId(R.id.signupButton)) //<= click the signup button in my UI
            .perform(click());
```

The first line up there opens the overflow menu and clicks the first item at the same time (which happens to be the signin item). So the test fails because it cannot find the MenuItem view. Is there anything I am doing wrong ? I am using an emulator API 22, compiling agains targetSdk 24 and using espresso 2.2.1.

Comment: I suppose that you're using ActivityTest Rule in your test class. Please try to use `openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(mActivityRule.getActivity());`

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
public class EspressoMatchers {    
    public static Matcher<View> withOverflowMenuButton() {
        return anyOf(allOf(isDisplayed(), withContentDescription("More options")),
                allOf(isDisplayed(), withClassName(endsWith("OverflowMenuButton"))));
    }
}
```

To open overflow menu:

```
onView(allOf(EspressoMatchers.withOverflowMenuButton(),
             isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.toolbar)))).perform(click());
```

Then it should work fine. Just use right ID for your `Toolbar`. I know this is just a copy from `Espresso` class, but I also ran into this issue and this helped me.

Please remember to always click the menu items "by name", not by their ID, as ID won't work. So your "click item" should be fine:

```
onView(withText("Sign in")) //<= click on the MenuItem
        .perform(click());
```

Comment: @mbonnin did you disable animations on your test device?